# React does not compile my component in which I'm trying to use react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been reading the official documentation of both React and React-pdf, as well as blogs, videos, but I still can't see what is making React throw a compilation error.

PDF.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet} from '@react-pdf/renderer'
import '../styles/PDF.css';

const PDF = () => {

    <div>
        <Document> 
            <Page size="A4" id="page">
                <View className="view">
                    <Text className="text">First section of the PDF document</Text>
                </View>
                <View className="view">
                    <Text className="text">Second section of the PDF document</Text>
                </View>
            </Page>
        </Document>
    </div>

}

export default PDF;
```

And when I import it directly into index.js it throws a compilation error.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles/index.css';
import PDF from './components/PDF.js';

ReactDOM.render(<PDF />,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The error

> **Failed to compile.**
>
> *./src/components/PDF.js*
>
> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: return it like: `return <><Document> ... </Document></>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to return the JSX in your PDF.js file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Page, Text, View, Document, StyleSheet } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import '../styles/PDF.css';

const PDF = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Document>
        <Page size="A4" id="page">
          <View className="view">
            <Text className="text">First section of the PDF document</Text>
          </View>
          <View className="view">
            <Text className="text">Second section of the PDF document</Text>
          </View>
        </Page>
      </Document>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PDF;
```